# How can I hide scrollble scroll in tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

how can i hide scroll-bar in using tailwind and here is my code

American Girls Jeans
            
            
              $25.00{" "}
              
                <s>$55.00</s>
              
            
            
              {starIcon}
              {starIcon}
              {starIcon}
              {starIcon}
              {starIcon}{" "}
            
            
              This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural
              lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit
              longer.
            
            
              
                {" "}
                ADD TO CART
              {" "}
              {heartIcon} 
              
                {heartIcon}{" "}
              
            
          
        
        
          
          
            
              American Girls Jeans
            
            
              $25.00{" "}
              
                <s>$55.00</s>
              
            
            
              {starIcon}
              {starIcon}
              {starIcon}
              {starIcon}
              {starIcon}{" "}
            
            
              This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural
              lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit
              longer.
            
            
              
                {" "}
                ADD TO CART
              {" "}
              {heartIcon} 
              
                {heartIcon}{" "}
              
            
          
        
        
          
          
            
              American Girls Jeans
            
            
              $25.00{" "}
              
                <s>$55.00</s>
              
            
            
              {starIcon}
              {starIcon}
              {starIcon}
              {starIcon}
              {starIcon}{" "}
            
            
              This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural
              lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit
              longer.
            
            
              
                {" "}
                ADD TO CART
              {" "}
              {heartIcon} 
              
                {heartIcon}{" "}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is this question ? Or robot generated fillers

Comment: C'mon. How can this even be your tailwind-css code!!!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you can do it using tailwind's built-in class but you can add this in your index.css where you have put `@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities;`
or main css file to hide the scroll bar

```
@tailwind base;

/* Chrome, Edge, and Safari */
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}


@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```